# How to generate Live hash key for PayUMoney android

Tags: android, payumoney

I am trying integrate PayUmoney android SDK  in my application,i integrate successfully But i face one problem.

in test mode they provide url to generate hask key but live they wont provide

Test mode: https://test.payumoney.com/payment/op/calculateHashForTest

For Live Mode:???

```
i am trying below Code to generate  Live Hash key 

   String salt="saltkey";
            String hashSequence=key+"|"+txnid+"|"+amount+"|"+productinfo+"|"

+firstname+"|"+email+"|"+""+"|"+"|"+""+"|"+""+"|"+""+"|"+salt;

            String serverCalculatedHash= hashCal("SHA-512", hashSequence);
            paymentParam.setMerchantHash(serverCalculatedHash);
            PayUmoneySdkInitilizer.startPaymentActivityForResult((Activity) 
context, paymentParam);  

  BUt i got  below response from sdk

 {"status":-1,"message":"key is not valid","result":null,"errorCode":null,"responseCode":null}

{"status":-1,"message":"payment status for :1111322345","result":"PP1 not updated till now from P2","errorCode":null,"responseCode":null}


 please give solution to:
1. generate live hash key using url,  
2.why above mention response return from PayUMoney SDk

Expecting your valuble answer.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for generate Live hash key for PayUMoney android

```
 public static String hashCal(String type, String str) {
        byte[] hashseq = str.getBytes();
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
            algorithm.reset();
            algorithm.update(hashseq);
            byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();
            for (int i = 0; i<messageDigest.length; i++) {
                String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF &messageDigest[i]);
                if (hex.length() == 1) {
                    hexString.append("0");
                }
                hexString.append(hex);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {

        }
        return hexString.toString();
    }
```

And call like

```
  String serverCalculatedHash = hashCal("SHA-512",MERCHANT_KEY+"|"+txnId+"|"+Double.parseDouble(totalPrices)+"|"+productName+"|"
                +userName+"|"+userEmail+"|"+udf1+"|"+udf2+"|"+udf3+"|"+udf4+"|"+udf5+"|"+MERCHANT_SALT);
```

serverCalculatedHash contain hash key for PayUMoney

Comment: i will try and let u know

Answer (score 0):

Check your payu dashboard at Integration Credentials: Merchant Key and Merchant Salt will be available.

Also check the .setIsDebug(true)  // For Integration environment - true, For Production - false.

You specified that Hash
String hashSequence=key+"|"+txnid+"|"+amount+"|"+productinfo+"|"+firstname+"|"+email+"|"+""+"|"+"|"+""+"|"+""+"|"+""+"|"+salt;

It should be :

hashSequence=key+"|"+txnid+"|"+amount+"|"+productinfo+"|"+firstname+"|"+email+"|"+udf1+"|"+udf2+"|"+udf3+"|"+udf4+"|"+udf5+"|"+udf6+"|"+udf7+"|"+udf8+"|"+udf9+"|"+udf10+"|"+salt;

user define string can be empty, but it has to passed in hash sequence.